# What changes do I have to make to the below code to keep from repeating the last output record?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

My task is to read data from an input file that has 10 records, with each field separated by a semicolon (;), then write to an output file. But in the output file, I have to use a space, instead of a semicolon (;). But the problem is that in the output file, I'm getting 11 records with the last record repeated. Below is the code which I have written. Can you tell me what I have to do?

```
*-----------------------------------------------------------------
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                              
*-----------------------------------------------------------------
     OPEN INPUT VA0001R.                                          
     OPEN OUTPUT VA0001W.                                         
     PERFORM MAIN-PARA UNTIL WS-EOF = 'Y'.                        
     PERFORM CLOSE-PARA.                                          
 CLOSE-PARA.                                                      
     CLOSE VA0001R.                                               
     CLOSE VA0001W.                                               
     GOBACK.                                                      
 MAIN-PARA.                                                       
     READ VA0001R INTO WS-VA0001W                                 
     AT END MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF                                    
     NOT AT END                                                   
     DISPLAY "WS-VA0001W=" WS-VA0001W                             
     CONTINUE                                                     
     MOVE SPACES TO WS-VA0001W.                                   
     UNSTRING REG-VA0001R DELIMITED BY ";"                        
        INTO WS-CODISIN,WS-MARKETING-REPORT,WS-LAST-UPDATE1,      
        WS-ANNUAL-REPORT,WS-LAST-UPDATE2,WS-STATUTES,             
        WS-LAST-UPDATE3,WS-FULL-BROCHURE,WS-LAST-UPDATE4,         
        WS-SEMI-ANNUAL-REPORT,WS-LAST-UPDATE5,WS-SIMPIE-BROCHURE, 
        WS-LAST-UPDATE6.                                          
     PERFORM WRITE-PARA.                                          
 WRITE-PARA.                                                      
     MOVE SPACES                TO   REG-VA0001W.                 
     MOVE WS-CODISIN            TO   CODISIN.                     
     MOVE WS-MARKETING-REPORT   TO   MARKETING-REPORT.            
     MOVE WS-LAST-UPDATE1       TO   LAST-UPDATE1.                
     MOVE WS-ANNUAL-REPORT      TO   ANNUAL-REPORT.               
     MOVE WS-LAST-UPDATE2       TO   LAST-UPDATE2.                
     MOVE WS-STATUTES           TO   STATUTES.                    
     MOVE WS-LAST-UPDATE3       TO   LAST-UPDATE3.                
     MOVE WS-FULL-BROCHURE      TO   FULL-BROCHURE.               
     MOVE WS-LAST-UPDATE4       TO   LAST-UPDATE4.                
     MOVE WS-SEMI-ANNUAL-REPORT TO   SEMI-ANNUAL-REPORT.          
     MOVE WS-LAST-UPDATE5       TO   LAST-UPDATE5.
     MOVE WS-SIMPIE-BROCHURE    TO   SIMPIE-BROCHURE.
     MOVE WS-LAST-UPDATE6       TO   LAST-UPDATE6.   
     WRITE REG-VA0001W.
```

I want to get 10 records in the output file but I'm getting 11 records. The last record is repeated and the input file has 10 records.

Answer (score 0):

When the input file is read for the eleventh time, the transfer of control is to `AT END`, `MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF`, then to `UNSTRING REG-VA0001R ...`. This is what is causing the repeated record.

The easiest solution is to add `EXIT PARAGRAPH` after `MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF`, assuming the compiler supports that.

Otherwise, restructure the paragraph to provide a different path for the transfer of control by removing some separator periods.

```
 MAIN-PARA.                                                       
     READ VA0001R INTO WS-VA0001W                                 
     AT END MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF                                    
     NOT AT END                                                   
         DISPLAY "WS-VA0001W=" WS-VA0001W                             
         MOVE SPACES TO WS-VA0001W                                 
         UNSTRING REG-VA0001R DELIMITED BY ";"                        
            INTO WS-CODISIN,WS-MARKETING-REPORT,WS-LAST-UPDATE1,      
            WS-ANNUAL-REPORT,WS-LAST-UPDATE2,WS-STATUTES,             
            WS-LAST-UPDATE3,WS-FULL-BROCHURE,WS-LAST-UPDATE4,         
            WS-SEMI-ANNUAL-REPORT,WS-LAST-UPDATE5,WS-SIMPIE-BROCHURE, 
            WS-LAST-UPDATE6
         PERFORM WRITE-PARA
     END-READ.
```

`AT END`, `MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF`, then `END-READ`.